# Sending play/pause requests to Pandora

Tags: python, pandora

What I am trying to start with is sending play and pause requests to Pandora.

However, the unofficial [Pandora API](https://6xq.net/pandora-apidoc/) documentation doesn't seem to mention how to do such a task.

I have also looked at an [implementation](https://github.com/pithos/pithos) of the API for Linux, but am just unable to understand where the most basic playback happens.

Comment: I __think__ that it goes as follows: You request a playlist from the API, and for each of the songs it returns, it gives you a temporary URL for the audio file on that server, which you then have to download and play using whatever you use to play audio files. So the play/pause functionality doesn't actually use the API at all. (This is a comment and not an answer because I really don't know if it's right or not.)

Comment: @ObliteraxScourgeofNations I would love to try out your theory, but unfortunately I never even got past the authentication stage!